# Finding a word in a specific cell and copy it to an adjacent cell using excell formula

Tags: excel

I have a problem.

Consider I have a text in a cell, let's say `A1 = United States of America`
Then, I want to copy **"States"** only to `B1`

Is there a formula for this? Considering you have A1 - A50 cells with different texts?
Note that you only want to copy a specific word from that text in that cell.

Comment: Do you want the the same word(States)from every cell or the word at the second position in the cell or the word which starts from "S"??

Answer (score 1):

Not so clear, but if you want to find the same word for every cells, you can use:

```
B1 ->    =IF(IFERROR(FIND($E$1;A1);"")<>"";$E$1;"")
```

and autocomplete. Considering that the word you search it's in E1.