# find and copy text in next column in excel

Tags: excel

I would like to know about excel find and copy text in next column in excel. I have a column A with text or sentences. I want to find a particular word and copy that word into next column that is column B only if that word is available in text of Column A.

Suppose Cell 1 of column A is:

"Execution of procedure and processes".

I want to search for word as "*Processes*" and that should copy in Column B (cell 1) "ONLY IF" processes word is available in text.

Could you please help me out in this?

One more thing to confirm that in the same formula, does it work if I want 2 words to find. Lets say 1 is processes and other is procedure. I want a single formula for both search words and it gives a single result with one word where applicable.

Comment: something similar to this (I think?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236226/finding-a-word-in-a-specific-cell-and-copy-it-to-an-adjacent-cell-using-excell-f?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put this in column B:

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("processes", A4)), MID(A4, SEARCH("processes", A4), 9), "")
```

it will copy the text from column A that matches (case-insentitive) the word "processes" to column B.

kaedinger's solution shows how to "parameterise" the search with a word in column C, which is a good thing.   If you wanted to copy the matching text from column A, you would need to measure the length of the word in column C, where I have hardcoded '9' above.

(ref: http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/compare-cell-contents-HP003056130.aspx)

Comment: I used this syntax but it is not working. In cell where there is no word like processes, it is copying.

Comment: Also it gives whole sentence as a result when word is matching. when word is not matching it is giving word that I want to copy

Comment: The first solution I gave did not "copy when there is no word like process" for me. However, I misread the question. My solution was case-sensitive, and copied the whole contents. I have edited the solution to pick out the not-case-sensitive match, and put the version from the A cell into the B cell (so that the contents of the B cell has the same case as the A cell). This screenshot shows it working: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qj92laropyxt8k8/Screenshot%202014-09-18%2008.42.59.png?dl=0

Comment: One more thing to confirm that in the same formula, does it work if I want 2 words to find. Lets say 1 is processes and other is procedure. I want a single formula for both search words and it gives a single result with one word where applicable.

Comment: I suggest you ask another question with the new requirement: describe the requirement clearly!

Answer (score 1):

For your special case:

"Execution of procedure and processes" in A1.
Formula in B1:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("processes", A1)), "processes", "")
```

`SEARCH("processes", A1)` searches the text `"processes"` in cell A1. If it is found, a number holding the position is returned, if it is not found, `NOTHING` is returned.

`ISNUMBER` checks if the returned value is a number. This is only the case if the word is found. If yes, the returned value is `true`, otherwise it is `false`.

`IF` in cell B1 evaluates `ISNUMBER`'s return value. If it is `true`, `"processes"` is returned, populating cell B1 with `"processes"`. If it is `false`, an empty text `""` is returned.

This can be summed up into the common case:

Text in A1.
Word to look for in C1.
Formula in B1:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C1, A1)), C1, "")
```

Evaluating to: if the text in C1 can be found in A1, put the text in C1 into B1, otherwise put an empty text into B1.

Comment: It is not working. Could you please guide me in said example only?

Comment: This solution works for me.  The difference between this solution and the one I posted is that this solution puts the comparison text in column B, whearas my solution puts the match text.

Comment: @Sharmil I extended the example. Please note that in different language versions of Excel the functions are called differently. In German you would do `=WENN(ISTZAHL(SUCHEN(C1; A1)); C1; "")`. Also note that even the _grammar_ may be different; in German you use semicolons where you'd put a comma in English versions.